# Picasso : want to cache a image without displaying it .so that i can use it later

Tags: android, picasso

I wanted to use picasso to cache images as i donot want to use it now ,may be later

what i get every where is

Picasso.with(this).load(url).into(imageView);

but what this does is load the image in image view in present.i dont want to use it right now.

Comment: Maybe you can set imageView visibility to GONE?

Comment: i thought it , but i dont want to do that,anything else

Comment: You can use a Target object. This will give you access to the bitmap and you can simple perform no task in the target object, so next time you load the URL into the ImageView it most likely will be taken from the cache. Have a look at their documentation: https://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/Target.html.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a temporary `Target` or `ImageView`, you can load it into the cache using [fetch](http://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.html#fetch--), followed later by [get](http://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.html#get--).

From the documentation on `fetch`:

> This is useful when you want to warm up the cache with an image.